# How to change variable class in child class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, inheritance

I have class UnitComponent that contains references to every script of the unit. Every unit has scripts UnitUI and UnitStats. So I can access UnitUI methods from UnitStats using UnitComponent class (for example: unitComponent.unitUI.SetHealthUI()). Of course, every script has a reference to UnitComponent class as well to be able to use it. These three scripts have children (PlayerComponent, PlayerUI, PlayerStats). These classes have new methods, for example PlayerUI has SetManaUI() method. But I can't use SetManaUI() using PlayerComponent without creating new variable with PlayerUI class because UnitUI variable doesn't have this method. Is there any option to make new methods accessible through variable unitUI by changing class to PlayerUI or I have to create new PlayerUI variable and somehow get rid of unitUI.

I've tried to make virtual empty method SetManaUI() in UnitUI class and override it in PlayerUI class to make everything work, but it seems like a bad practise because UnitUI can become full of useless empty virtual methods.

**Simplified version of scripts**

**Script that connects scripts together**

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Collector : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Stats stats;
    public UI ui;
}
```

*UI script*

```
using UnityEngine;

public class UI : MonoBehaviour
{
    Collector collector;
    public void UIMethod()
    {
        Debug.Log("UI method");
    }
}
```

**Stats script**

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Stats : MonoBehaviour
{
    Collector collector;
    public void StatsMethod()
    {
        Debug.Log("Stats method");
    }
}
```

**Child of collector script**

```
public class ChildCollector : Collector
{
    public string someNewData;
    public string someNewData1;
    public string someNewData2;

    public void Start()
    {
        ui.ChildUIMethod(); //has to be executed and write "Child UI method"
        stats.ChildStatsMethod(); //has to be executed and write "Child Stats method"
    }
}
```

**Child of UI script**

```
using UnityEngine;

public class ChildUI : UI
{
    ChildCollector childCollector;
    public void ChildUIMethod()
    {
        Debug.Log("Child UI Method");
    }
}
```

**Child of Stats script**

```
using UnityEngine;

public class ChildStats : Stats
{
    ChildCollector childCollector;
    public void ChildStatsMethod()
    {
        Debug.Log("Child Stats Method");
    }
}
```

**Full version of scripts**

**Unit Component script**

```
using UnityEngine;

public class UnitComponent : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Animator animator;
    public UnitStats unitStats;
    public UnitUI unitUI;
}
```

**UnitStats script**

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class UnitStats : MonoBehaviour
{
    public UnitComponent unitComponent;
    public float maxHealth;
    public float health;
    public List<GameObject> lootDrop;
    protected virtual void Start()
    {

        if (health <= 0 || health > maxHealth)
            health = maxHealth;
        unitComponent.unitUI.SetHealthUI(health, maxHealth);
        CheckDeath();
    }

    private void CreateDamagePopup(float takenDamage)
    {
        GameObject damagePopupCanvas = Instantiate(unitComponent.unitUI.damagePopupCanvasPref, transform.position, Quaternion.identity, transform);
        damagePopupCanvas.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = takenDamage.ToString();
        Vector3 randomPosOffset = new Vector3(Random.Range(-0.1f, 0.1f), Random.Range(-0.1f, 0.1f), 0f);
        damagePopupCanvas.transform.position += randomPosOffset;
        Destroy(damagePopupCanvas, 3f);
    }
    public float CalculateHealthPercentage()
    {
        return (health / maxHealth);
    }

    protected void CheckDeath()
    {
        if (health <= 0)
        {
            unitComponent.animator.SetTrigger("isDead");
            DropLoot();
        }
    }

    protected void CheckOverheal()
    {
        if (health > maxHealth)
        {
            health = maxHealth;
        }
    }

    public void DealDamage(int damage)
    {
        unitComponent.unitUI.healthBar.SetActive(true);
        health -= damage;
        unitComponent.unitUI.SetHealthUI(health, maxHealth);
        CheckDeath();
        CreateDamagePopup(damage);
    }

    public void HealCharacter(int heal)
    {
        health += heal;
        CheckOverheal();
        unitComponent.unitUI.SetHealthUI(health, maxHealth);
    }

    public void DropLoot()
    {
        foreach (GameObject item in lootDrop)
            Instantiate(item, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
    }

}
```

**UnitUI script**

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class UnitUI : MonoBehaviour
{
    public UnitComponent unitComponent;
    public GameObject damagePopupCanvasPref;
    public GameObject healthBar;
    protected Slider healthBarSlider;

    virtual public void Start()
    {
        healthBarSlider = healthBar.GetComponent<Slider>();
    }
    public virtual void SetHealthUI(float health, float maxHealth)
    {
        if (healthBarSlider)
            healthBarSlider.value = health / maxHealth;
    }

    public virtual void SetCoinsUI(int coinAmount) { } //Necessary for PlayerUI script working
    public virtual void SetManaUI(float mana, float maxMana) { } //Necessary for PlayerUI script working

}
```

**PlayerComponent script**

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerComponent : UnitComponent
{
    public PlayerMovement playerMovement;
    public PlayerSlot playerSlot;
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
}
```

**PlayerStats script**

```
using UnityEngine;
public class PlayerStats : UnitStats
{
    
    protected int coins;
    public float mana;
    public float maxMana;
    public float manaRegenPerSec;
    protected override void Start()
    {
        UI = gameObject.GetComponent<PlayerUI>();
        animator = gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>();
        if (health <= 0 || health > maxHealth)
            health = maxHealth;
        UI.SetHealthUI(health, maxHealth);
        UI.SetManaUI(mana, maxMana);
        CheckDeath();
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        if (mana < maxMana)
        {
            mana += manaRegenPerSec * Time.deltaTime;
            UI.SetManaUI(mana, maxMana);
        }
    }
    private void Awake()
    {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(this);
    }

    public void AddCoins(int amount)
    {
        coins += amount;
        UI.SetCoinsUI(amount);
    }
}
```

**PlayerUI script**

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PlayerUI : UnitUI
{
    [SerializeField] protected GameObject manaBar;
    [SerializeField] protected Text manaValue;
    [SerializeField] protected Text healthValue;
    [SerializeField] protected Text coinValue;
    protected Slider manaBarSlider;
    
    public override void Start()
    {
        healthBarSlider = healthBar.GetComponent<Slider>();
        manaBarSlider = manaBar.GetComponent<Slider>();   
    }
    public override void SetHealthUI(float health, float maxHealth)
    {
        healthBarSlider.value = health / maxHealth;
        healthValue.text = health.ToString() + "/" + maxHealth.ToString();
    }

    public override void SetManaUI(float mana, float maxMana)
    {
        manaBarSlider.value = mana / maxMana;
        manaValue.text = Math.Round(mana).ToString() + "/" + Math.Round(maxMana).ToString();
    }
    public override void SetCoinsUI(int coinAmount)
    {
        coinValue.text = coinAmount.ToString();
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you post your classes as **code** please? It is a bit hard to follow in raw text and makes it easier to understand the concept and find possible solutions/alternatives

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189 for code formatting.

Comment: Sure. Give me 5 minutes

Comment: Well, there are many possible ways to achieve this. 1. You could cast the unitUI variable inside of PlayerComponent to PlayerUI, because you know that it is of type PlayerUI. 2. You could make Unit a generic: Unit<T>, where T is the type of the UI, then you would avoid casting 3. You could go without inheritance and save the PlayerUI directly on the Player... There are many solution, the optimal way depends on your overall structure and what exact problem you are trying to solve.